# What will be the default speed to play the mp3 file through NAudio

Tags: naudio

What will be the default Speed set to play the MP3 files through NAudio waveout.
Is there any way to set the speed according to the User setting in NAudio waveout.

Thank's in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The default will be normal playback speed. There is a Windows API call called [waveOutSetPlaybackRate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743873%28VS.85%29.aspx), but this is not necessarily supported on all soundcards. You would be better off finding alternative ways to speed up the audio.

Comment: Hi Mark, Can you please provide any sample code or algorithm to change the Speed or Tempo for MP3 audio files.